# Verilog: variable assignment to virtual interface?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Sorry if I had this stupid question...I've been trying to google for answer but couldn't find one. :(

I have a problem assigning a variable to a virtual interface. For example:

```
Param.sv
...
string MyInput[3];
MyInput[0] = Signal_CLK; //Storing SignalName to in an Array.
MyInput[1] = Signal_Tx;
MyInput[2] = Signal_Rx;
...


MyInterface.sv
...
Signal_CLK = dut.MicroController.Source.clk; //Signal destination
Signal_Tx = dut.MicroController.Tx_01;
Signal_Rx = dut.MicroController.Rx_01;
...


Test.sv
virtual MyInterface my_vif
logic [7:0] read_value;
....
for (i = 0; i <3; i++ )
begin
    read_value = my_vif.My_Input[i];
    ..
    //some logic to compare read_value with spec//
    ..
end
```

The problem is when compiling, it doesn't translate `my_vif.My_Input[0]` into `my_vif.***dut.MicroController.Source.clk***`. Instead, it thinks that the path is `my_vif.***My_Input[i]***`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the compiler thinks you are trying to access my_vif.My_Input[i] is because you are. The My_Input[] array is a completely separate string array; not part of the virtual interface. When using the "thing.thing.thing" syntax, the compiler will loyally follow it, so it will expect there to be something called My_Input that has some elements (as its an array) as a member of the interface given by my_vif.

However, looking over youre code, you are trying to have My_Input[i] replaced at compile time, which is very different. The compiler will not run your loop, look in My_Input[i] and find the string "Signal_CLK" and replace that as part of the path to get the path my_vif.Signal_CLK. Nor can it do that at run time.

I dont know of a generic solution to looking over any variables in an interface; though Im also not sure if thats really what you want. IF you provide more details on the rest of your checker, we might be able to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use strings to look up identifiers by name within SystemVerilog. There are tool specific and C interfaces that may let you do this, but that would be very inefficient. The best way to do this by using a combination of abstract/concrete classes and the bind construct. See these references: http://events.dvcon.org/2012/proceedings/papers/01P_3.pdf and http://www.doulos.com/knowhow/sysverilog/DVCon08/DVCon08_SysVlog.php